# MS SQL & PHP to return table from database but it is returning random letters

Tags: php, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have been trying to show tables from my MS SQL into my browser using the following php code but it is returning table with random letters please see screenshots and code below

this is the code I am using

```
     <?php

/* ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); */





function databaseOutput()

 {
  $serverName = "*************"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "*******"=>"********", "UID"=>"******", "PWD"=>"*******!");
$db = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


  $dbQuery = sqlsrv_query($db, "select * from vw_Impact_Return2 ");
  $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery);

    //print('<pre>');
    //print_r($rows); 
    //print('<pre>');
    //exit;

  foreach($rows as $dbRow) {
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Schema_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Stakeholder_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Intended_Changes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Investment_Type_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Value_of_Investment']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Summary']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Description']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Indicator']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Source']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Quantity']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Duration']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Start']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Financial_Proxy']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Deadweight']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Displacement']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Attribution']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Drop_Off']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Impact']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year0']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year1']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year2']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year3']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year4']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year5']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php

  }

} // end of function databaseOutput()

if (isset($_POST['submit_docs'])) { // word output

  header("Content-Type:application/msword");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=test.docx");

?>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> Social Return</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Schema_ID</th><th>Stakeholder_ID</th><th>Intended_Changes</th><th>Investment_Type_ID</th><th>Value_of_Investment</th><th>Summary</th><th>Outcomes_Description</th><th>Outcomes_Indicator</th><th>Outcomes_Source</th><th>Outcomes_Quantity</th><th>Outcomes_Duration</th>
        <th>Outcomes_Start</th><th>Outcomes_Financial_Proxy</th><th>Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy</th><th>Deadweight</th><th>Displacement</th><th>Attribution</th><th>Drop_Off</th><th>Impact</th>
        <th>Return_Year0</th><th>Return_Year1</th><th>Return_Year2</th><th>Return_Year3</th><th>Return_Year4</th><th>Return_Year5</th>
      </tr>
      <?php databaseOutput(); ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
<?php

  exit; // end of word output

}
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Social Return</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dunluce.infc.ulst.ac.uk/cw11ba/project/Project/mycss.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="export_form" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="submit_docs" value="Export as MS Word" class="input-button" /> <a href="https://dunluce.infc.ulst.ac.uk/cw11ba/project/Project/admin.php"><button type="button" class= "btn btn-block">Go back to Admin Area</button></a>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="student">
      <tr>
        <th>Schema_ID</th><th>Stakeholder_ID</th><th>Intended_Changes</th><th>Investment_Type_ID</th><th>Value_of_Investment</th><th>Summary</th><th>Outcomes_Description</th><th>Outcomes_Indicator</th><th>Outcomes_Source</th><th>Outcomes_Quantity</th><th>Outcomes_Duration</th>
        <th>Outcomes_Start</th><th>Outcomes_Financial_Proxy</th><th>Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy</th><th>Deadweight</th><th>Displacement</th><th>Attribution</th><th>Drop_Off</th><th>Impact</th>
        <th>Return_Year0</th><th>Return_Year1</th><th>Return_Year2</th><th>Return_Year3</th><th>Return_Year4</th><th>Return_Year5</th>
          </tr>
      <?php databaseOutput(); ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Database table looks like this]

[image: Code returning this]

Please please help me, I have tried everything and I can only connect to my database via sqlsrv_connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) returns a single row as an array, so in your foreach you're not looping through what you think you are. Try doing a while loop instead:

```
  while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Schema_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Stakeholder_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Intended_Changes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Investment_Type_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Value_of_Investment']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Summary']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Description']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Indicator']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Source']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Quantity']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Duration']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Start']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Financial_Proxy']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Deadweight']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Displacement']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Attribution']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Drop_Off']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Impact']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year0']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year1']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year2']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year3']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year4']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year5']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php

  }
```

Comment: Hi Mate, I still got the same issue "Schema_ID Stakeholder_ID Intended_Changes Investment_Type_ID Value_of_Investment Summary Outcomes_Description Outcomes_Indicator Outcomes_Source Outcomes_Quantity Outcomes_Duration Outcomes_Start Outcomes_Financial_Proxy Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy Deadweight Displacement Attribution Drop_Off Impact Return_Year0 Return_Year1 Return_Year2 Return_Year3 Return_Year4 Return_Year5

Warning: Illegal string offset 'Schema_ID' in E:\kunden\homepages\12\d728593166\www\test.php on line 31
C" this is what I am getting now

Comment: Try `var_dump($dbRow);` at the top of your loop to see what data it contains.

Comment: I just did   while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?> again and it worked for some reasons thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help! Be sure to hit the checkmark next to the answer, so that the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: Done Thank you :)